# How to implement Picasso image loading library in android?

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

I am new to android I have tried Glide library with [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1f4CvPvwvZ4&list=PLDKucuCBdlJacuFlSOpy3wi30ezUKzH2v&index=6), but I want to use Picasso library.

Code I am using currently:

```
Glide.with(this).load(currentUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(navUserPhoto);
```

Comment: Learn about Picasso library in the documentation

Comment: Hello Welcome to stackoverflow please read this [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(viewHolder.imageView);

Comment: For more details try project link: https://github.com/square/picasso, For implementation try this : https://www.journaldev.com/13759/android-picasso-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import picasso library to your project:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

2. Use picasso instead of Glide:

```
Picasso.get().load(currentUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(navUserPhoto);
```

Go through picasso [documentation](https://square.github.io/picasso/) if you require extra modifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
//install this one in to the build.gradile(Module)
//in dependencies
//After sync the project
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```